# .EAP Enterprise Architecture

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, enterprise-architect

I have a .EAP file with a folder with .java files, and some SQL queries. I've never worked with enterprise architecture, is it possible to compile and run an enterprise application on eclipse ? I'm not even sure if an .EAP file is a solution file or a program that can run . Can anyone lead me in the right direction and what is needed ? I have installed the necessary JDKs and JREs .  Please help anyone .

Comment: Go and read what the vendor tells about his product.

Comment: just a hint: The product name is _enterprise architect_, not enterprise architecture

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out, Enterprise Architect is a UML modelling tool and nothing else. It does, however, include functionality for forward and reverse engineering of source code (in various languages) and also has the ability to invoke external compilers.

For Eclipse specifically, you need an additional product (also from Sparx Systems) called [MDG Integration for Eclipse](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/int/eclipse/index.html).

The .EAP file is the model repository (also known as a "project" in EA parlance), which is opened by EA. It roughly (very roughly) corresponds to a Visual Studio solution or an Eclipse workspace. From inside EA, you can generate code from models (which does not require the MDG Integration) and invoke external compilers.

Whether this is a good way of working is of course another matter, and if you are not familiar with EA but are familiar with Eclipse I'd recommend just generating the code once, and then importing it into an Eclipse workspace and taking it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Architect is a tool for UML modeling. It stores its projects in .eap files. Internally this file is MS Access database.

UML model can have a class model as its part. Enterprise Architect is able to import classes to this class model. I think .java files are sources for classes previously imported to your UML model.

UML model is just model. You have to deploy and run your code in its own way. Of course you can use Eclipse as an IDE for your Java application. But this has nothing to do with the Enterprise Architect UML model. (I know Enterprise Architect can be used for running and debugging but I didn't used it for this purpose and it's not the typical usage of this UML modeling tool.)

Enterprise Architect can model SQL database as well. In order to run your SQL queries you need a SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You need an application called [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) sold by [Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) to open .eap files.

Comment: is an EAP file a solution file ?

Comment: An EAP file is a M$ Access database.

Comment: so that means this java app use Access DB ? does that mean I have to setup a ODBC ?

Comment: i just installed enterprise architect and it opened. all the java files, interfaces etc opened . so does this enterprise architect run applications ?

Comment: when I opened the EAP file , it created a ms access db in the same folder

Comment: That is a temporary file, removed when you close the project.